# HTTP PUT deleting triples in sesame

Tags: apache, tomcat, curl, put, sesame

I'm trying to use http PUT via cURL to update my triple store in openrdf-sesame, but I've hit a problem that I can't find a solution for.

When using POST, the triple data uploads perfectly.

But then using PUT, instead of adding the data provided, it deletes all the data from my repository. I've ran cURL in verbose mode, and it's giving back the expected HTTP status code.

I've added

```
<init-param>
<param-name>readonly</param-name>
<param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
```

to Apache Tomcat's web.xml,
Ive also tried the guide here: [HTTP PUT Guide](http://www.codereye.com/2010/12/configure-tomcat-to-accept-http-put.html), but that hasn't helped either.

**EDIT**
Here are the cURL commands from my batch file:

```
call "%curl%" -# -X POST %endpoint%/statements -H "Content-Type:application/x-trig;charset=UTF-8" -d @%%X
call "%curl%" -# -X PUT %endpoint%/statements -H "Content-Type:application/x-trig;charset=UTF-8" -d @%%X
```

Which is essentially:

```
curl.exe -# -X POST http://myendpoint/statements -H "Content-Type:application/x-trig;charset=UTF-8" -d @MyTrigFile.trig
curl.exe -# -X PUT http://myendpoint/statements -H "Content-Type:application/x-trig;charset=UTF-8" -d @MyTrigFile.trig
```

For the moment, I've disabled authentication, but otherwise I'd also include a `-u user:password` argument.

Comment: How about showing the cURL commands that you're using (both the successful `POST` one and the unsuccessful `PUT` one)?

Comment: Given that the data in your repository is deleted, the problem is (probably) not your Tomcat config, since if the repository is emptied, the command must have come through to Sesame. Most likely cause is that the input RDF data you supply is somehow malformed. Like @cygri said, can you show the exact curl command(s) you execute?

Comment: Relevant part of the Sesame documentation: http://www.openrdf.org/doc/sesame2/system/ch08.html#d0e341

Comment: I've updated my original post with the cURL commands now. I've also read through the documentation, and it seems to follow point 8.6.1.5, unless I'm missing something obvious (which I wouldn't put past myself!)

Answer (score 0):

I have just ran some tests using your exact way of invoking curl, and I can't reproduce the problem (using Sesame version 2.6.8): it works as expected here.

The only possible cause I can think of is that your TriG file has a syntax error which Sesame fails to report back.

Another possible problem is your expectations: the command as you execute it will completely clear the *entire* repository and replace the data with the contents of your TriG file. Were you perhaps expecting something else?

To further debug this, can you have a look in the Sesame server logs and tell us if it shows any warnings or errors? Server logs are viewable by going to `http://<server:port>/openrdf-sesame/`  in the browser and clicking 'System' in the menu on the left.

Comment: Yes, I have got some errors, they are all along the lines of:

 2012-08-17 09:34:54,544 repositories/TestRepo  [Rio error] '31 Dec 1989' is not a valid value for datatype http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date (1, -1)

Comment: I get the same errors when using POST, the only difference being that POST still uploads the data properly

Comment: The datatype errors are something you might want to fix, but it is not what is causing this problem I think. Sesame is normally configured to report such errors in the log but to accept the data anyway.